# Codeigniter passing multiple parameters issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

My function in `users` class:

```
public function form($a = false, $b = false, $c= false)
{
   // Something to do
}
```

My request uri:

```
..admin/users/form/1/2/3
```

I'm getting 404 error:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

But If i try alphabetical characters like `admin/users/form/1/something/1` instead of numeric `2` or `1` places, it works.

So;

```
..admin/users/form/1/2   > works
..admin/users/form/1/2/3 > not work
..admin/users/form/a/2/3 > works
..admin/users/form/1/a/3 > works
..admin/users/form/1/2/a > not work
```

And i tried with custom routes and remapping but again i couldnt figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
$route['admin/users/form(/:any)*'] = 'admin/users/form';
```

Then use uri segments in your controller:

```
public function form()
{
   $a = $this->uri->segment(4);
   $b = $this->uri->segment(5);
   $c = $this->uri->segment(6);
}
```

I'm not sure why your initial setup isn't working because I always use routes this way. Works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was using custom routing but i didnt expect because of custom function. And i fixed now. Thanks again for efforts.